# How to use customize to turn on viper mode by default?

Tags: customize

You can enable viper mode with `M-x viper-mode RET`, but this is inconvenient to do so every new buffer.

I see on the [Viper page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html%5Fmono/viper.html) that the way to turn on viper mode by default is

```
 (setq viper-mode t)
 (require 'viper)
```

I've been trying to move over to using customize to do emacs configuration. Is there a way to turn on viper mode on start using customize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable `viper` using `customize`, you will need to do something like this.

## Enable `viper-mode` for new buffers

1. Load customize with `M-x customize`
2. Search for `package`
3. Then search for `package load list`
4. Press `<RET>` to expand the arrow next to `Package Load List`
5. After the last entry, press `<RET>` on the `INS` button to insert a new line.
6. Press `<RET> 1` on the `Value Menu` button on the second line to insert a specific package.
7. Delete `nil` and put `viper`.
8. Press the `Apply and Save` button at the top.  At the prompt type `yes`.

[image]

These steps will not enable `viper` for the splash screen or the default `*scratch*` buffer.  To do those, we will need to do more...

## Change the default `*scratch*` mode to `viper-mode`

1. From the main `M-x customize` menu, search for `Initial Major Mode`
2. Press `<RET>` on the arrow next to `Initial Major Mode` to expand it.
3. Replace `list-interaction-mode` with `viper-mode`
4. Press `<RET>` on the `Apply and Save` button at the top and then type `yes`

[image]

## Disable the splash screen

I'm not sure how to set the default mode for the splash screen using `customize`, so let's just disable it:

1. From the main `M-x customize` menu, search for `startup`
2. Press `<RET>` on the arrow next to `Inhibit Startup Screen` to expand it
3. Press `<RET>` on the `Toggle` button
4. Press `<RET>` on the `Apply and Save` button at the top and type `yes`

[image]

At some point in this process, or when you reload Emacs, you will be presented with the `viper` startup screen which asks whether you want to "Viperize".  Follow the prompts accordingly.

---

I ran into lots of problems with the settings persisting while trying this out.  Hopefully everything works for you!

In my opinion, while it is a noble effort to make Emacs more accessible to newcomers, the utility of `customize` is limited.  You will get a *far* greater return on investment learning some basic Emacs Lisp. To start, I recommend reading the [excellent documentation about `init.el`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) and [An Introduction to Programming Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/index.html).

That said, here's how to do what you want using Emacs Lisp:

1. Create a file named `init.el` in the `~/.emacs.d/` directory.
2. In it, put

   (viper-mode)

The next time you start Emacs, `viper-mode` will be enabled.